# Black faces on cycles render

Tags: rendering

While rendering animation black objects and faces appear.
They appear at specific frames. The problem is with geometry nodes, I guess. When I change values in nodes for animation, black objects appear on different cubes. I am new to blender and modeling so it may be hard for me to explain something.

Here is my blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gWpJhHf3xnIdQr6xNmHtaWfUBohVgsCQ/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: just don't leave it without reaction ... ussually happens as z-fight (double face at the same location), but since I tried to check your setup I don't see a reason for that ... so probably graphic card? Try to check blender's Bug Tracker if not posted already.

Comment: @vklidu, I just redid it in a new file and that issue hasn't appeared. Actually have no idea what was the problem, but yeah probably faces were getting on each other somehow.